# Make an getApplication API request for Amazon Q using POSTMAN

Tags: amazon-web-services

`https://qbusiness.us-east-1.api.aws/applications/ApplicationID`

It gave this error -

```
{"Message":"User: arn:aws:iam::071327047843:user/amazonq-user is not authorized to perform: qbusiness:GetApplication on resource: arn:aws:qbusiness:us-east-1:071327047843:application/ApplicationID because no identity-based policy allows the qbusiness:GetApplication action"}
```

How to resolve it. (Here I replaced my actual application Id with ApplicationID )